# Error Syncing DOORS to Rhapsody using the Gateway Tool

Tags: rhapsody, ibm-doors

I am using the Rhapsody Gateway tool to synchronize my DOORS requirements with my Rhapsody model, and I get the following error:

*Some errors occurred:
Failed to move requirement_id under Requirements Doc
Exception while synchronizing requirement requirement_id*

I get the same error for approx. 10 requirements out of several hundred - so most are syncing fine.

I've done a search on the web, but have not seen anyone experiencing the same error.  Does anyone know what could cause this error?

DOORS version 9.1.0.0
Rhapsody version 7.6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

If the Unit containing the requirements is write protected, this error occurs.
Check the write protection of the model unit (corresponds to a file containing it) and remove it.

Comment: The Unit containing the requirements is set to Read/Write, if not I get a different error.  Other requirements in the same Unit are synchronizing correctly.

Comment: You Write about error in move, ist the Target Unit  also writable?

Comment: Yes, the target Unit is set to Read/Write.